# Issues to get or transform an inserted value with PyQt5 into int or float

Tags: python, user-interface, sdk, pyqt5

I am trying to develop a GUI with Python in order to run the Impedance Analyzer of an Analog Discovery 2 from Digilent. So far, I found the Waveforms ADK for several setups of the analyzer and I decided to use as an interface tool PyQT5, because TKinter was giving several headaches. Code is below.

```
import PyQt5.QtWidgets as qtw
import PyQt5.QtGui as qtg
from ctypes import *
from dwfconstants1 import *
import math
import time
import sys
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

if sys.platform.startswith("win"):
    dwf = cdll.LoadLibrary("dwf.dll")
elif sys.platform.startswith("darwin"):
    dwf = cdll.LoadLibrary("/Library/Frameworks/dwf.framework/dwf")
else:
    dwf = cdll.LoadLibrary("libdwf.so")


class MainWindow(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setWindowTitle("Impedance with AD2")
        
        self.setLayout(qtw.QVBoxLayout())
        
        my_label = qtw.QLabel("Insert values required to run impedance")
        
        my_label.setFont(qtg.QFont('Helvetica',24))
        self.layout().addWidget(my_label)
        
        #Entry
        
        start = qtw.QLineEdit()
        start.setObjectName("start_frequency")
        start.setText("Insert initial frequency in Hz")
        self.layout().addWidget(start)
        
        stop = qtw.QLineEdit()
        stop.setObjectName("stop_frequency")
        stop.setText("Insert final frequency in Hz")
        self.layout().addWidget(stop)
        
        steps = qtw.QLineEdit()
        steps.setObjectName("stop_frequency")
        steps.setText("Insert number of steps")
        self.layout().addWidget(steps)
        
        reference_resistor = qtw.QComboBox(self, editable = True, insertPolicy = qtw.QComboBox.InsertAtTop)
        reference_resistor.addItem("1K", 1000)
        reference_resistor.addItem("100", 100)
        reference_resistor.addItem("10",10)
        self.layout().addWidget(reference_resistor)
        
        my_button = qtw.QPushButton("Launch measurement!", clicked = lambda: press_it())
        self.layout().addWidget(my_button)
        
        
        mytext = qtw.QTextEdit(self, acceptRichText = False, lineWrapMode =qtw.QTextEdit.FixedColumnWidth,
                                readOnly = False, placeholderText = "Hello World!")
        
        version = create_string_buffer(16)
        dwf.FDwfGetVersion(version)
        
        hdwf = c_int()
        szerr = create_string_buffer(512)
        #print("Opening first device")
        dwf.FDwfDeviceOpen(c_int(-1), byref(hdwf))
        
        mytext.setText(f'DWF Version: "+str(version.value). "Opening first device"')
        
        if hdwf.value == hdwfNone.value:
            dwf.FDwfGetLastErrorMsg(szerr)
            
            mytext.setText(f'DWF Version: +str(szerr.value). Failed to open device')
            print(str(szerr.value))
            print("failed to open device")
            quit()
        
        dwf.FDwfDeviceAutoConfigureSet(hdwf, c_int(3)) 
        sts = c_byte()
        
        self.show()
        
        def press_it():
            my_label.setText(f'Reference resistor is {reference_resistor.currentData()}')
            #start.setText("")
            mytext.setPlainText("Intended values of running AD2")
            dwf.FDwfAnalogImpedanceReset(hdwf)
            dwf.FDwfAnalogImpedanceModeSet(hdwf, c_int(8)) # 0 = W1-C1-DUT-C2-R-GND, 1 = W1-C1-R-C2-DUT-GND, 8 = AD IA adapter
            dwf.FDwfAnalogImpedanceReferenceSet(hdwf, c_double(reference_resistor)) # reference resistor value in Ohms
            dwf.FDwfAnalogImpedanceFrequencySet(hdwf, c_double(start.text)) # frequency in Hertz
            dwf.FDwfAnalogImpedanceAmplitudeSet(hdwf, c_double(0.09)) # 1V amplitude = 2V peak2peak signal
            dwf.FDwfAnalogImpedanceConfigure(hdwf, c_int(1)) # start
            time.sleep(2)
            
            rgHz = [0.0]*steps_
            rgRs = [0.0]*steps_
            rgXs = [0.0]*steps_
            for i in range(steps):
                hz = stop_ * pow(10.0, 1.0*(1.0*i/(steps-1)-1)*math.log10(stop_/start_)) # exponential frequency steps
                print("Step: "+str(i)+" "+str(hz)+"Hz")
                rgHz[i] = hz
                dwf.FDwfAnalogImpedanceFrequencySet(hdwf, c_double(hz)) # frequency in Hertz
                time.sleep(0.01) 
                dwf.FDwfAnalogImpedanceStatus(hdwf, None) # ignore last capture since we changed the frequency
                while True:
                    if dwf.FDwfAnalogImpedanceStatus(hdwf, byref(sts)) == 0:
                        dwf.FDwfGetLastErrorMsg(szerr)
                        print(str(szerr.value))
                        quit()
                    if sts.value == 2:
                        break
                resistance = c_double()
                reactance = c_double()
                dwf.FDwfAnalogImpedanceStatusMeasure(hdwf, DwfAnalogImpedanceResistance, byref(resistance))
                dwf.FDwfAnalogImpedanceStatusMeasure(hdwf, DwfAnalogImpedanceReactance, byref(reactance))
                rgRs[i] = abs(resistance.value) # absolute value for logarithmic plot
                rgXs[i] = abs(reactance.value)
                
                for iCh in range(2):
                    warn = c_int()
                    dwf.FDwfAnalogImpedanceStatusWarning(hdwf, c_int(iCh), byref(warn))
                if warn.value:
                    dOff = c_double()
                    dRng = c_double()
                    dwf.FDwfAnalogInChannelOffsetGet(hdwf, c_int(iCh), byref(dOff))
                    dwf.FDwfAnalogInChannelRangeGet(hdwf, c_int(iCh), byref(dRng))
                    if warn.value & 1:
                        print("Out of range on Channel "+str(iCh+1)+" <= "+str(dOff.value - dRng.value/2)+"V")
                    if warn.value & 2:
                        print("Out of range on Channel "+str(iCh+1)+" >= "+str(dOff.value + dRng.value/2)+"V")

            dwf.FDwfAnalogImpedanceConfigure(hdwf, c_int(0)) # stop
            dwf.FDwfDeviceClose(hdwf)

            plt.plot(rgHz, rgRs, rgHz, rgXs)
            ax = plt.gca()
            ax.set_xscale('log')
            ax.set_yscale('log')
            plt.show()
        
app = qtw.QApplication([])

mw = MainWindow()

app.exec_()

# create the instance of our Window 
  
# start the app 
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

The idea is that a single GUI is displayed, I insert the values of the initial and final frequency, the number of steps and select the reference resistor
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H60Qx.png) and then press the button and do the part of the Waveforms SDK running the sweep for impedance, but this error appears:

```
  File c:\users\bforcure\documents\trials with pyqt5.py:91 in press_it
    dwf.FDwfAnalogImpedanceReferenceSet(hdwf, c_double(reference_resistor.text)) # reference resistor value in Ohms

AttributeError: 'QComboBox' object has no attribute 'text'
```

How can I transform the value from reference_resistor into an integer? I tried with int() and it says that only accepts strings or floats, not "QComboBox". Is there a way when I can refer directly to the value and convert it.

Comment: Always check the documentation of the classes you're using: as you can see from the [QComboBox](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html) docs, there's absolutely no property (or function/method) that is simply named "`text`", even considering inherited classes (always check the `Inherits:` field in the doc header, and the "List of all members, including inherited members" field they often contain). Also, Qt property getters are *callables*, so you must always use parentheses. Finally, please avoid greetings in posts: while some of us may appreciate them, they are actually pointless and unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Your `reference_resistor` is a `QComboBox`.

Like the error message tells you, `QComboBox` does not have a `text` attribute,
so your `c_double(reference_resistor.text)` is bound to fail.

If you look at [the documentation for `QComboBox`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QComboBox.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QComboBox.currentText),
you will find that it has a `currentText()` method instead.

You can use that to get the current value from inside the ComboBox:

```py
text = reference_resistor.currentText()
# you may want to add some error handling here, as your combobox is editable
resistor_value = int(text)
```

Additionally, you currently added one of the resistors the following way:

> `reference_resistor.addItem("1K", 1000)`

As the text `"1K"` is not a valid integer, the snippet above would not work for this case, unless you changed it to "1000". You seem to intend to use the `userData` field to get that value out of the field. That can be done using the `currentData()` method, instead of `currentText()`, so:

```py
resistor_value = reference_resistor.currentData() #already an integer
```

In that case I would suggest making the combobox non editable though, as `currentData()` returns the last selected Item even after the text was edited.